# Update multiple tables with laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have to update multiple tables in one request ... For this I create a method where i wrote :

```
$sector = Sector::where('sectors.id', '=', $id)
    ->join('valuechains', 'sectors.id', '=', 'valuechains.sector_id')
    ->join('lang_valuechain', 'valuechains.id', '=', 'lang_valuechain.valuechain_id')
    ->join('segments', 'valuechains.id','=', 'segments.valuechain_id')
    ->join('lang_segment', 'segments.id', '=', 'lang_segment.segment_id')
    ->join('keyneeds', 'segments.id', '=', 'keyneeds.segment_id')
    ->join('keyneed_lang', 'keyneeds.id', '=', 'keyneed_lang.keyneed_id');
 $sector->update(
    ['sectors.deleted_at' =>  Carbon::now()],
    ['lang_sector.deleted_at'  => Carbon::now()],
    ['valuechains.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()],
    ['lang_valuechain.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()],
    ['segments.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()],
    ['lang_segment.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()],
    ['keyneeds.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()],
    ['keyneed_lang.deleted_at' => Carbon::now()]
);
```

Unfortunatelly i have an error message concerning 'updated_at' :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Champ: 'updated_at' dans field list est ambigu (SQL: update `sectors` inner join `valuechains` on `sectors`.`id` = `valuechains`.`sector_id` inner join `lang_valuechain` on `valuechains`.`id` = `lang_valuechain`.`valuechain_id` inner join `segments` on `valuechains`.`id` = `segments`.`valuechain_id` inner join `lang_segment` on `segments`.`id` = `lang_segment`.`segment_id` inner join `keyneeds` on `segments`.`id` = `keyneeds`.`segment_id` inner join `keyneed_lang` on `keyneeds`.`id` = `keyneed_lang`.`keyneed_id` set `sectors`.`deleted_at` = 2018-05-10 17:54:51, `updated_at` = 2018-05-10 17:54:51 where `sectors`.`id` = 2 and `sectors`.`deleted_at` is null)

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you are trying to do cascading soft deletes. You might want to investigate using a package to help make this easier, you can check out a package to achieve this [here](https://github.com/michaeldyrynda/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes). Here is some sample code from the documentation:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Comment;
use Iatstuti\Database\Support\CascadeSoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Post extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes, CascadeSoftDeletes;

    protected $cascadeDeletes = ['comments'];

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Alternatively I would recommend doing this was a raw query as I don't think QueryBuilder is suited for this type of situation.